# SPSS - import large CSV files

Tags: csv, spss

I'm trying to load big CSV file into SPSS and nothing happens. I'm stuck at Text Import Wizard - Delimited Step 4 of 6 for a lot of hours. Is there any way to import the data or to see errors if exists?

Comment: How large are the files, in terms of records and columns ?

Comment: For example 430 records, 832 columns.

Comment: That is a rather small file. SPSS can handle that. Definitely not file size is the problem here

Comment: So how can I found out what is the problem? Is there some log?